# codeigniter and timezones

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am based in the UK but my site runs on a server in america. Some of the dates that go into the database reflect the server time and some reflect the UK time. I am confused how this happens.

I have set the timezone in the codeigniter index.php file using `date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Dublin');` It seems to work for some controllers and not for others.

Any recommendations on where to look for the problem. Should i use the timezone function in the constructor of every controller?

Comment: What php code do you use to make and store those dates?

Answer (score 0):

Your controller may extends the same one controller CI_Controller
You can try add code in the constructor,CI_Controlle is the file

```
System/core/Controller.php
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably using two different ways of determining time. Maybe in some instances it is determined clientside, you used strtotime and date in a different way...

The generally accepted method to deal with that is to input Unix timestamp and/or have a single method that determines the correct time. Then instead of messing wih controller in system folder (you'll have to do it every time you upgrade), extend the controller with MY_Controller in the aplication's core folder and either define /determine the time zone there - either one will probably do.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because MySQL uses the server timezone and probably not configured to your timezone. Best solution is to configure the server to suit your timezone.

However, I was once faced this same situation and there was no room to change the server (it had other american sites). So, I was forced to set the timezone for MySQL on each request. I know that it is not ideal, but it works.

I have a library that is autoloaded in my app, then I put a DB call on the constructer of that class. I have the timezone set in my config file.

```
$CI = &get_instance();

// Let's set timezone in the DB
$timezone = new DateTimeZone($CI->config->item('app_timezone'));
$offset = $timezone->getOffset(new DateTime("now")); // Offset in seconds
$gmt_offset = ($offset < 0 ? '-' : '+') . str_pad(floor($offset/3600), 2, '0') . ':' . str_pad(($offset % 3600)/60, 2, '0');

$CI->db->query("SET time_zone = '{$gmt_offset}'");
```

Answer (score -1):

It depends on how you insert the dates into your db.

You can solve this by inserting timestamps into your db as integers using strtotime or time.
When displaying dates in your view, convert them back with date or strftime

Settings the timezone in the main index.php should be sufficient.